# FInding the the most frequent value for a particular year in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, dataset

In postgre, I want to find the user(s) who has the highest number of "opened" requests in the year 2011 for the following database. I am new to postgre and I am stuck with this.

```
ID  PERSON      REQUEST   DATE
4   datanoise   opened  2008-09-02 
5   marsuboss   opened  2009-09-02 
6   m3talsmith  opened  2009-09-06 
7   sferik  opened  2010-09-08 
8   sferik  opened  2010-09-09 
8   dtrasbo discussed   2010-09-09 
8   brianmario  discussed   2011-09-09 
8   sferik  discussed   2011-09-09 
9   rsim    opened  2011-09-09 
.....more tuples to follow
```

this is just a small part of the database, there are around 250,000 tuples in total.

Comment: Anything you've tried so far? Something involving `where` `group by` `sum` `order by` maybe?

Comment: Very similar to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66086757/finding-the-highest-after-grouping-by-month/66087227) ; if you want year 2011 you should remove the SQL about extracting the month, and add in the where clause: date>='2011-01-01' and date < '2012-01-01' to only scan the year you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest aggregates, and in any case you need the whole top row ordered by count:

```sql
select person, count(request) as countRequests
from table
where (date >= '2011-01-01' and date < '2012-01-01')
    and request = 'opened'
group by person
order by countRequests desc
limit 1;
```

The best way to filter by date is to use a half-open interval i.e. `>= start and < dayAfterEnd`

Comment: will this give a single output of the person with the maximum number of "opened requests" in 2011  or multiple outputs ?

Comment: the query should output the name of the person who had the maximum number of "opened " requests in 2011, not all requests

Comment: but u r not placing any filter on the request type, it should only be " opened" requests!

Comment: Do you need ones that have been opened at any point, or that are still open, or that were still open at the end of 2011?

Comment: I need only the tuples where in the request colums, it is "opened"

Comment: instead of open, putting "opened" and I think it will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following

```
 WITH CTE(ID,PERSON,REQUEST,DATE) AS
  (
    SELECT 4,'datanoise','opened','2008-09-02'
       UNION ALL  
    SELECT 5,   'marsuboss',   'opened',  '2009-09-02' 
       UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 ,  'm3talsmith',  'opened' , '2009-09-06' 
       UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 ,  'sferik' , 'opened',  '2010-09-08' 
       UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 ,  'sferik',  'opened' , '2010-09-09' 
       UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 ,  'dtrasbo', 'discussed',   '2010-09-09' 
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 ,  'brianmario',  'discussed' ,  '2011-09-09' 
       UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 ,  'sferik',  'discussed',   '2011-09-09' 
       UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 ,  'rsim',    'opened',  '2011-09-09' 
   )
   SELECT C.PERSON,COUNT(C.ID)CNTT
      FROM CTE AS C
      WHERE C.DATE >= '2011-01-01'AND  C.DATE<'2012-01-01'
         AND C.REQUEST='OPENED'
      GROUP BY C.PERSON 
      ORDER BY COUNT(C.ID)DESC
      LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: the tuples I provided a re justt a fraction of the actual database, the actual database contains 250,000 tuples....

Comment: I have edited the question, please have a look at it

Comment: amended. Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for more than one person.  That suggests using window functions:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM (SELECT T.PERSON, COUNT(*) AS CNT,
             RANK() OVER (OVER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS SEQNUM
      FROM T
      WHERE T.DATE >= '2011-01-01'AND T.DATE < '2012-01-01' AND
            T.REQUEST = 'OPENED'
      GROUP BY T.PERSON 
     ) P
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Or if you are using Postgres 13+, you can use `WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT T.PERSON, COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM T
WHERE T.DATE >= '2011-01-01'AND T.DATE < '2012-01-01' AND
      T.REQUEST = 'OPENED'
GROUP BY T.PERSON
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```